# Apache, encode source URL before redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch 301 ^(/static-data.*/)$ /check?target=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

And before redirect I want urlencode "target" value via .htaccess.
This is possible?

Comment: Can you provide some example to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options All -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(static-data.*)$ http://domain.tld/check?target=$1 [R=301,B,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

This - all requests that return 403 or 404 will be redirected to the checker, and this statistics of "lost requests" will be seeing admin.